# How can I control the size of specific cell in Grid?

Tags: grid-lines

I have this code with `Grid` and would like to customize the size of each cell separately, is that possible?
For example in this code:

```
Grid[{{3!, 20!, SpanFromLeft}, {10!, 10!, 10!}}, 
 ItemSize -> {{5, 5, 5}}, Frame -> All, 
 Alignment -> {{Left, Right, Right}, {Right, Left, Left}}]
```

I want to change the size of the first cell only such that its right vertical line moved to the left as shown in the fig below.

[image: the actual output of the above code above the desired output]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding a fourth column to the grid & merging the appropriate cells:

```
Grid[
 {{3!, 20!, SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft}, {10!, SpanFromLeft, 10!, 10!}},
 ItemSize -> {{0.5, 3, 5, 5}},
 Frame -> All,
 Alignment -> {{Left, Right, Right}, {Right, Left, Left}}
 ]
```

[image]

If you don't need to fine-tune the column widths, you can also omit the `ItemSize` option:

```
Grid[
 {{3!, 20!, SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft}, {10!, SpanFromLeft, 10!, 10!}},
 Frame -> All,
 Alignment -> {{Left, Right, Right}, {Right, Left, Left}}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: that looks great, may you please elaborate on the meaning of numbers in `ItemSize -> {{0.5, 3, 5, 5}}`. why do you choose 0.5, 3 and then 5?

Comment: @valarmorghulis I just played around with the values to make it look good. Essentially, 0.5 is the width of the `3!`, 0.5+3 the width of the `10!` below (since it is spanning the first two columns), and so on. If you don't need to do fine tuning, you can simply remove the whole `ItemSize -> ...` setting, and it will automatically choose the widths properly (see also the edited answer)

Answer (score 4):

Assume there are 4 columns, with appropriate `SpanFromLeft`-s:

```
   Grid[{
      {3!, 20!, SpanFromLeft},
      {10!, SpanFromLeft, 10!, 10!}},
     ItemSize -> {{Scaled[.01], Automatic}},
     Frame -> All, 
     Alignment -> {{Left, Right}}]
```

[image]

Comment: that is Awesome! just one question please, how can I make the three cells in the second row equally in size?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you want, but it may be good enough?

```
Column[{
  Row[Framed /@ {3!, 20!}],
  Row[Framed /@ {10!, 10!, 10!}]
  }, Spacings -> -.1]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for sharing your thoughts, but I do really need it with Grid